# Undefined AJAX "data" property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to update some text within `<span>` fields on a parent form via a modal. To do this I am using an AJAX call on the modal form to retrieve the new user entered values. Once the "Save" button is clicked, the modal form should retrieve the textbox values and send them back.

However I am unable to pass any values back. When debugging in the function that creates a Javascript array, the values exist and are correct. However once I try to use the `data` property of the AJAX call (ex: `data.Address`), it returns undefined.

Here is my code for the AJAX call:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data:
            {
                ID: $("#clientID-@Model.Id").val(),
                Address1: $("#clientAddress1-@Model.Id").val(),
                Address2: $("#clientAddress2-@Model.Id").val(),
                City: $("#clientCity-@Model.Id").val(),
                Province: $("#clientProvince-@Model.Id").val(),
                PostalCode: $("#clientPostalCode-@Model.Id").val(),
                PhoneNumber: $("#clientPhoneNumber-@Model.Id").val()
            },
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#Address1-@Model.Id").html(data.Address1);

            alert(data); //prints the entire HTML for the form
            alert(data.ID); //prints undefined
            alert($("#clientID-@Model.Id").val()); //prints the correct value - 2827
            alert("Data logged!");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error occurred!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is data??? `console.log(data);`

Comment: Sometimes using a function as an ajax parameter makes troubles. Try loading the data into a variable, and then make the ajax call with the variable instead of the function. And try console.log(data) inside the success function to check what is returned.

Comment: @Skatch I've updated the OP to remove the other function. I am not sure how to bring up the console window for an MVC project in VS 2012. I am using FF for testing purposes but have never debugged with it.  I am still really confused about why the 3 alerts print such different things. In the 2nd and 3rd, it is literally the same value being passed.

Comment: In firefox, press F12. Start debugging with the browser, DO NOT debug with `alert`'s

Comment: *"alert(data); //prints the entire HTML for the form"* Then your server isn't returning something you can get an ID from.

Comment: if ` alert(data); //prints the entire HTML for the form` prints really the html code of a form, you wont be able to get any data using array syntax. it seems that you are expecting an other data format for return as what you really get.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you, I will use that from now on!

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sending the correct header from the server that say is json you must specified in the ajax object that the response is json try adding the `dataType`

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data: getModelData(),
    success: function (data) {
        //$("#Address1-@Model.Id").html(data.Address1);
        alert(data[0].Address1);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error occurred!");
    }
});
```

Or in the server specified the content type `application/json`

Comment: The `error` method is always called no matter what else I do. I have omitted that specific property so that it will detect what I am using. I am not sure as I did not build the foundation of the project I am working on. Would there be anyway to check the content type?

Comment: in the google chrome console, go to the network, click on the ajax call that you make and then in the right you will see the response headers, see the content-type header, if you are saying that always call the error method, please check for the status code of the response if is correct (200, 304) in the same tab that i already mentions

Comment: It is Status Code 200 (OK) and the content-type header is "text/html; charset=utf-8". I will specify `text/html` as the datatype property.

Comment: If you will read json response as json is better that you make the in the response header the content-type as application/json see the SPEC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt